# Access Control Exception (java.net.SocketPermission 127.0.0.1:8080 connect,resolve)

Tags: java, html, applet, permission-denied

I am trying to read remote pdf file using applet. It works fine when i run only applet from my IDE but it throws SocketPermission exception when i embed it in object tag of html...
Following is html to access applet

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="300" width="550">
        <param name="code" value="MyApplet" />
        <param name="archive" value="applet.jar" />
        <param name="filePath" value="https:path_to_pdf.pdf">
        Applet failed to run.  No Java plug-in was found.
    </object>
```

and this is how i am trying to read file in applet

```
URL url;
url = new URL(pdfUrl);

InputStream in = null;
try {
    in = url.openStream();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MyApplet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

DONE SO FAR:
I have added my local url in java exception list for certificate issues.
I have also created policy file to grant all permissions and put in home directory...

here is exception details

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "example.com:443" "connect,resolve")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:457)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
at sun.plugin2.applet.SecurityManagerHelper.checkConnectHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:510)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)
at MyApplet.printPdf(MyApplet.java:162)
at MyApplet.actionPerformed(MyApplet.java:118)
at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Button.java:409)
at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Button.java:377)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Don't use applets in 2015! Use JNLP (aka Java WebStart)

Comment: i am checking JNLP because i am unfamiliar to it. but i think its again using applet tags of html and applets tags are deprecated as per my information. fge

Answer (score 0):

You are running the applet on your local computer. You dont use `https`. You use `file://`.

```
file://path/to/your/pdf/file.pdf
```

Comment: I am accessing remote pdf file not local pdf file.